# scala extend class with overloaded method

Tags: scala, overloading, extend

I am trying to extend class with overloaded method so I can instantiate it and pass different number of argument but keep common type of Foo and Bar. How can I make my code runnable?

```
class GenericClass {
  def run(x: Int): Unit
  def run(x: Int, y: Int): Unit
}

class Foo extends GenericClass {
  def run(x: Int): Unit
}

class Bar extends GenericClass {
  def run(x: Int, y: Int)
}

def getRun(hello: String) = {
  hello match {
        case "foo" => new Foo
        case "bar" => new Bar
        }
}

def execIt(runType: String) = {
    case "foo" => getRun(runType).run(2)
    case "bar" => getRun(runType).run(2, 3)
}

execIt("foo")
```

Comment: Since a `Foo` is also a `GenericClass` it has to provide both alternatives, that si the point of polymorphism. I really do not see why you need all those classes at all, why not just an object with both methods and the match to call the method on the object.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are you trying to achieve? Seems like you are trying to apply logic from another language(args in python for example) in Scala, which might not work. What is the purpose of doing that? What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @Tomer Shetah I do not try to introduce the logic from other language. I try to solve the problem explained in the question.

Comment: @ Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez the fact you do not see why I need it does not imply I do not need it.

Comment: @darkman if I didn't saw why you need that is not implying you do not need it, it is just saying that for the way the question was formulated those were not needed. Also, as Tomer, said the question was unclear and it gives the impression that it was about an XY-problem. And if in fact you only needed to solve the problem of the question as stated and you solved it using `???` to throw a **NoImplementedException**, then let me tell you that you have what is called a failed abstraction and as such it would be better to rethink is design now and not latter when it already caused problems.

Comment: No, I did not solved it with NoImplementedException. You have misread answer from @Dmytro Mitin. I solved it as he proposed with option 1 so with one trait with two classes which overide type and method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to introduce a type member

```
trait GenericClass {
  type In
  def run(x: In): Unit
}

class Foo extends GenericClass {
  override type In = Int
  override def run(x: Int): Unit = println("Foo#run")
}

class Bar extends GenericClass {
  override type In = (Int, Int)
  override def run(x: (Int, Int)): Unit = println("Bar#run")
}

def getRun(hello: String) = {
  hello match {
    case "foo" => new Foo
    case "bar" => new Bar
  }
}

def execIt(runType: String) = getRun(runType) match {
  case foo: Foo => foo.run(2)
  case bar: Bar => bar.run(2, 3)
}

execIt("foo") // Foo#run
```

or a type class

```
trait GenericClass
class Foo extends GenericClass
class Bar extends GenericClass

trait Run[A <: GenericClass, T] {
  def run(a: A, t: T): Unit
}
object Run {
  implicit val foo: Run[Foo, Int] = (a, t) => println("Run.foo")
  implicit val bar: Run[Bar, (Int, Int)] = (a, t) => println("Run.bar")
}

implicit class RunOps[A <: GenericClass](val a: A) extends AnyVal {
  def run[T](t: T)(implicit r: Run[A, T]): Unit = r.run(a, t)
}

def getRun(hello: String) = {
  hello match {
    case "foo" => new Foo
    case "bar" => new Bar
  }
}

def execIt(runType: String) = getRun(runType) match {
  case foo: Foo => foo.run(2)
  case bar: Bar => bar.run(2, 3)
}

execIt("foo") // Run.foo
```

Please notice that I modified `execIt` as well.

Also you can keep everything as is and just throw `NotImplementedError` for methods that aren't needed

```
trait GenericClass {
  def run(x: Int): Unit
  def run(x: Int, y: Int): Unit
}

class Foo extends GenericClass {
  def run(x: Int): Unit = println("Foo#run")
  def run(x: Int, y: Int): Unit = ???
}

class Bar extends GenericClass {
  def run(x: Int): Unit = ???
  def run(x: Int, y: Int) = println("Bar#run")
}

def getRun(hello: String) = {
  hello match {
    case "foo" => new Foo
    case "bar" => new Bar
  }
}

def execIt(runType: String) = runType match {
  case "foo" => getRun(runType).run(2)
  case "bar" => getRun(runType).run(2, 3)
}

execIt("foo") // Foo#run
```

although this last option seems to abuse OOP.

Comment: wow, the first trick did the job. Thank you!